# I am getting undefined parameter when i use post_edit method in meteor. How to update meteor collection?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, simple-schema

```
//My collection
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import PostSchema from './schema';

const Posts = new Mongo.Collection('Posts');

Posts.attachSchema(PostSchema);

export default Posts;

//My schema
import SimpleSchema from "simpl-schema";

export default new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        autoValue: function() {
            if (this.isInsert) {
                return new Date();
            } else if (this.isUpsert) {
                return {$setOnInsert: new Date()};
            } else {
                this.unset();  // Prevent user from supplying their own value
            }
        }
    },
    userId: {
        type: String,
        autoValue: function(){ return this.userId }
    }
});    

//My methods file

     import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
        import Posts from "/imports/api/posts/collection";
        import Security from '/imports/api/security.js';

        Meteor.methods({

            'post_create' (data) {
                if (!data) {
                    throw new Meteor.Error('error', 'Make sure you have filled all the fields! ;)', 'Some details');
                } else if (Security.checkLoggedIn(this.userId)) {
                    console.log("Are you sure you logged in?");
                } else {
                    return Posts.insert(data);
                }

            },
            'post_get': function (id) {
                   if (Security.checkLoggedIn(this.userId)) {
                    console.log("Are you sure you logged in?");
                } else {
                    return Posts.find({id}).fetch();
                }
            },

            'post_remove': function (id) {
                if (Security.checkLoggedIn(this.userId)) {
                    console.log("Are you sure you logged in?");
                } else {
                    return Posts.remove({_id: id});
                }
            },

    //My problem is here! When I call this method in the postEdit.jsx file i get title prop undefined
            'post_edit': function (data) {

                if (Security.checkLoggedIn(this.userId)) {
                    console.log("Are you sure you logged in?");
                } else {
                    Posts.update(data,{
                        $set: {
                            title: this.data.title,
                            description: data.description
                        }
                    });
                }enter code here
            }
        });

    //My PostEdit.jsx
    import React from "react";
    import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
    import {createContainer} from "meteor/react-meteor-data";
    import {AutoForm, AutoField, TextField} from "uniforms-unstyled";
    import PostCreateSchema from "./PostCreateSchema";

    export default class PostsEdit extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {loading: true, Posts: []}
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            Meteor.call('post_get', (err, res) => {
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    Posts: res
                })
            })
        }

        handleEdit(data) {
            Meteor.call('post_edit',data, (err, res)=> {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Register error', err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Your post have been changed", res);
                }
            })
        }

        render() {
            if (this.state.loading) {
                return <div>Waiting for the method</div>
            }

            return (
                <div>
                    {
                        <ul>
                            {
                                this.state.Posts.map(posts => {
                                    return (

                                        <AutoForm schema={PostCreateSchema}
                                                  onSubmit={this.handleEdit.bind(this)}
                                                  placeholder
                                                  key={posts._id}
                                        >
                                            <h4>Title: {posts.title}</h4>
                                            <h4>Description: {posts.description}</h4>
                                            <AutoField name="title"/>
                                            <TextField name="description"/>
                                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                                        </AutoForm>
                                    );
                                })
                            }
                        </ul>
                    }
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

//I am trying for hours to understand how can i fix this. I understand that the problem is at the parameters and that they are undefined....but i don't know how can i give a correct value to the key. Any tip/link/advice is highly apreciated.

Comment: Can you also share a snippet of the actual error log?  You are using ```autoform``` and ```simplschema```. If I remember right, autoform update method  takes in two parameters. ```(doc, id)``` In your case you're only passing the ```doc``` as ```data```

Comment: this.data will not be defined in Meteor.method.
`title: this.data.title,` >> `title: data.title,`

Comment: Also your next error will be the `Posts.update` call, as I don't think `data` is appropriate for the `selector` field in this call.  Add `console.log(data)` at the start of your 'post_edit' method to see what data you have in this object.

Comment: Hy Jeremyk and thanks for reply.

Comment: Normaly the method is used in this way with an id parameter and data parameter but i try many other ways to see how it works 'post_edit': function (id, data) {

        if (Security.checkLoggedIn(this.userId)) {
            console.log("Are you sure you logged in?");
        } else {
            Posts.update(id,{
                $set: {
                    title: data.title,
                    description: data.description
                }
            });
        }
    }

Comment: Exception while invoking method 'post_edit' TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined. I have done console log of data and it shows me an object with the parameters that i have inserterd in the fields from the form but it will not save the data in my collection. I also have notice that my id is undefined when i did a console log of the id.

Comment: When I add an id parameter to the Meteor.call, that id itseld is undefined but the method is working, thus is not updating the data collection.         `Meteor.call('post_edit', data.id, data, (err, res)=> {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Register error', err);
            } else {
                console.log(data.__id);
                console.log("Your post have been changed", res);
            }
        })`